# Admin - no Featured image choice in create new/page|post

Tags: posts, theme-development, pages, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I am developing a WP theme and I wanted to add a thumbnail/featured image to a new page/post but there is no such option/choice - like it used to be, I am using WP 3.8.1, I did try to turn off all the plugins - didnt help, I also checked the console for any errors - no error.

Interesting is that with the native "Twentyfourteen" theme it works/shows.

Any idea what might cause this behaviour? Is there anywhere anything what could turn this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your theme has not registered support for post thumbnails.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Description) You need to add one of these as appropriate:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) );          // Posts only
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'page' ) );          // Pages only
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'movie' ) ); // Posts and Movies
```

See the Codex (link above) for more information.

Comment: Since when is this needed ? :) BTW: It is working fine now.

Comment: Since when? Since thumbnails were rolled into the Core, I think, though I am not sure.

Comment: So I just didnt noticed that before because themes which needed it where based on existing themes x) , thanks for the info! btw: they should really turn this on by default...